# Is there a way to add a request parameter for all post requests in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I need to add a token to each post request in jmeter. I have tried using Http Request defaults but it isn't working.

Comment: Please provide a screenshot sample for the POST request in question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible with some scripting.

1. Add [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) to your Test Plan (at the same level as your HTTP Requests)
2. Put the following code into the PreProcessor's "Script" area:

   ```
   sampler.addArgument("token", "token_value");
   ```

   Replace `token` and `token_value` with your actual data

When you run the test Beanshell PreProcessor will be executed before each sampler and add the parameter to each [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) in scope.

References:

- `sampler` stands for HTTPSamplerBase class instance, see [HTTPSamplerBase JavaDoc](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerBase.html#addArgument(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) for detailed information on methods and fields
- [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) - comprehensive information on using Beanshell scripting in JMeter tests with some examples

Comment: Thanks Dimitri, worked like a charm. `if(sampler.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("post")){ sampler.addArgument("token", vars.get("VALUE")); }` restricted the execution to POST methods.

Answer (score 1):

Http Request Defaults worked for me. I added name=test and value=test1 to my Http Request Defaults and for POST I got:

> https://localhost:7002/TestConditionPost
>
> POST data:
>   test1

and for GET:

> https://localhost:7002/TestConditionGet?test=test1