# Is there a way to add parameter to requests for embedded resources in Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am testing a web application. I use option Retrieve All Embedded Resources with enabled Parallel downloads in HTTP Request settings. I would like to add a parameter to all requests (including requests for embedded resources)

I have tried BeanShell preprocessor and Http requests defaults, as described [Is there a way to add a request parameter for all post requests in jmeter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40361048/is-there-a-way-to-add-a-request-parameter-for-all-post-requests-in-jmeter#)
However, the parameter is not being passed to requests for embedded resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to identify the embedded resources which is required like css,jss,javascript etc and remove that are not required. Then, you can put all those request under bzm@parallel controller to be executed in parallel. In that way you can pass any variable to all the embedded request as they are normal http samplers.
You can use [HTTP Request default](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults) to send one parameter to all request or via coding as shown in the link provided.

[image]

For more information check below links:-

https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter-how-properly-handle-embedded-resources-html-responses/

https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, it really works. However, it seems that with parallel controllers the test is using a lot of CPU of WebSeal server. So I would prefer using the built-in feature Retrieving embedded resources..

Comment: @xor Please check this :-https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers  . It help others.